# Export Basis spline information to matlab

Tags: splines, knots

i am new to Mathematica. I have generated the contours of this image with the following code [image]

```
img = Import["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/archive/0/09/20160903181541%21Twitter_bird_logo.png"];`

mesh = ImageMesh@img;
midpoints = Midpoint /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1];
Graphics[{Thick, Darker[Red], 
  BSplineCurve[midpoints, SplineClosed -> False]}]
```

My question is: is there a way to get from Mathematica the vector of control points,the vector of knots,the vector of weights of control points and degree of this B-Spline/NURBS curve?

Comment: Do you mean export to Matlab or Mathematica ? Can you check the title of your post ?

Comment: I mean how can i export from mathematica to matlab

Comment: By the way, the reason for the bad spline is because if you look closely, there is a small black dot and another dot above it. You can fix it with this code: `imgFixed = ColorReplace[FillingTransform[Binarize[img], 1], {
   White -> RGBColor[{0., 0.6745, 0.9294}], Black -> RGBColor[{0, 0, 0, 0}]}]`

Comment: Use `bsf=BSplineFunction[midpoints]` , then `bsf["ControlPoints"]` `bsf["Knots"]`, and `bsf["Degree"]` to get them. `bsf["Weights"]` just seems to return `Automatic`. I don't know about how you want them exported to Matlab though.